# Reusing variables stored in Viewbag, performance? (Recycling Viewbags)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, viewbag

When I think of a `ViewBag`, I associate it with the "*final say*."

Meaning you do all your logic and set the results to it.

```
ViewBag.A = Some crazy math formula;
ViewBag.B = Another crazy math formula;
ViewBag.GrandTotal = Some crazy math formula + Another crazy math formula;
```

**This works as well:**

```
ViewBag.A = Some crazy math formula;
ViewBag.B = Another crazy math formula;
ViewBag.GrandTotal = ViewBag.A + ViewBag.B;
```

Yipes, I am working with variables that formulate at runtime!

Is this in anyway absurd or inefficient?

Comment: I question why you need to store `GrandTotal` in the viewbag when it's just a calculated field.  For simplicity I would stick with option 2, I doubt that the performance implication of accessing viewbag properties is tangible at all.

Comment: ViewBag is basically just a `Dictionary<string, object>`, except you can reference the entries with dots instead of indexing it.  There isn't anything magic going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### tl;dr: The `ViewBag` is a lazily over-used "get out of jail free card" for storing data that basically leaves you saying "hey, just throw errors at run-time, so who really cares?"

> Is this in anyway absurd?

**Most definitely!** If you're performing complex logic/formulas based entirely upon `ViewBag` values, then you're just opening the door for a load of potential run-time errors.

You should really strongly type them, put them in models. Then at least that way you can alleviate *some* of the potential run-time errors or possible flaws in your implementation.

To me, the only plausible use for the `ViewBag` (other than `ViewBag.Title`) is when your model can be **many** different types that are in no way related (if the types were related, you'd have them all derive from a common item and put your property on that item).

**It's MVC (Model View Controller), not VVC (ViewBag View Controller) which is what some people seem to think/implement.**

In terms of performance, I'd say the difference is *insignifiant* to warrant the use of it.

Comment: Only the last sentence of that is relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: I'd say it's all relevant since the answer is essentially: don't use the ViewBag for this kind of stuff, and really, don't use it at all unless you have a darn good reason to. ViewBag is *abused* far too often; everyone needs to hear what @mattytommo wrote and hear it often.

Comment: @Pinch thanks for that edit. BTW `tl;dr` isn't a mistake it's just an internet phrase that means `too long; didn't read`. People do that to provide a summary of an answer when the answer is deemed *too long* :)

Answer (score 3):

Your second option is obviously more performant than the first. This has nothing to do with using the ViewBag or not, it's just that you are only performing the calculations once.

Apart from that, using the ViewBag is not very efficient since you need boxing to put a value type on the heap and later a cast to emit the value into the view.

The correct way to do this is through a model:

```
public class MyModel{

    public decimal A {get; set; }
    public decimal B {get; set; }
    public decimal GrandTotal { get { return A + B;}}
}
```

Then in your controller just instantiate this class, put the variables in and pass it to the view:

```
** snip **
MyModel model = new MyModel {A = some crazy formula, B = another crazy formula};
return View(model);
```